# How to split the JSON format value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the JSON format data as key,value pair of data `without using map`.Please find the below json data.

`var data={"123":"test1","2365":"test2","1233":"test3","112365":"test4"}`

I want to split as like below output :

`key : 123 value : test1
key : 2365 value : test2`

```
 success: function (data) {
        $.each(response.data, function(value,key) {
        return {label: key+","+value,value: key,desc : value};
        });
```

Comment: Without using `map`? Why? That `$.each` doesn't help much, that `return` does nothing useful.

Comment: Because IE8 won't support

Comment: It will if you use jQuery's `$.map`.

Comment: $.map works in IE8 and works pretty much the same way.

Comment: But in any case, you don't return stuff in asynchronous code, you use the callbacks to do the logic... See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Are you just looking for a long string with multiple "key" and "value" associations?

Comment: Yes, for autocomplete

Comment: In just getting the value, but autocomplete drop is not closing after select the value

Answer (score 0):

[As per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/), the order for the callback function variables is `key`, `value` not `value`, `key`. You're returning at the first iteration of your each loop also, perhaps you should add to an array in the loop and return the array at the end? You've also got `response.data` which I assume is probably `data.response`?

```
success: function(data) {
    var output = [];
    $.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
        output.push([key, value]);
    });
    return output;
}
```

That's just an example, obviously you'll want to restructure that array so that you can actually use the key and value...

[Here's a jsFiddle example for this](http://jsfiddle.net/7f49S/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    var data = { "123": "test1", "2365": "test2", "1233": "test3", "112365": "test4" };

    var result = "";
    for (var key in data)
    {
        result += "key:  " + key + "  value: " + data[key] + "  ";
    };

    alert(result);
```

Comment: Yes , I'm looking like this..Let me finish and come back.